# How to get array from txt in c++

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I know its really simple question, but i cant find answer by myself.
I got txt file in this form:

- 0 0 0 0
- 1 16 0 1

  2 32 0 1

  3 48 0 1

  b 16 16 0

For now i have:

```
std::ifstream odczyt2;
odczyt2.open("dodatki/textures.txt");
if (odczyt2.is_open())
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 39; x++)
        {
            odczyt2 >> textury[x][y];
        }
    }
}
odczyt2.close();
```

And i want to make array of chars, which will look exacly the same.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want.  It looks like you are reading in the file so do you have a problem with that or is your issue with displaying the contents?

Comment: What you are trying to do is c and there are at least two issues with it: you cannot use `istream::operator>>` to extract to `char *`, and you need to preallocate the memory. The c++ way would be to use a `vector<vector<string>>`...

Comment: Is the last line of data correct?  It doesn't fit the pattern of the other lines.

Comment: *which will look exacly the same* --- the same as what?